# jquery tabs not working on safari

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, safari, tabs

i'm using jquery version 1.11.1 and jquery-ui version 1.10.0 I have jquery code which works fine on the page but i have jquery tabs works on chrome and firefox but not working on latest versions of safari. I have downlodad safari 5.1.7 on windows for testing. All items in tabs are displayed as tabs are not there at all. Newer versions of safari have the same issue with the same page. So what's the correct version of jquery or jquery-ui that makes tabs works fine on safari

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
    show: 'fade', hide: 'fade'
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last version of Windows Safari was released on May 9, 2012, at which point JQuery UI was on a 1.8, and JQuery on a 1.7 release.  Apple no longer make Safari for Windows.

As Safari is no longer supported for windows, unless you have a particular reason for using it, I can see no reason to browser test for this.  Windows Safari users (if there are still any) are risking security issues of an unsupported browser, and presumably increasingly broken websites, due to missing out on 4 years of updates.

Getting it to work for Windows Safari is likely to give your site a messier code base.  Not keeping JQuery up-to-date to support it also seems a bad decision.

Ideally, Safari needs to be tested on the latest iOS version.  Testing on the windows version was never a good substitute for this, and certainly is not now that it is so out-of-date.

Comment: Further to this, if by "Newer versions of safari " - you mean the latest iOS version, you may wish to re-compose your question to clarify this, as that would be a bigger issue.

Comment: I'm testing on my windows because Mac users with safari are having the same issue on the latest safari version. Tabs are not working. I don't have a Mac so I use safari 5.1.7 on windows just to test it and it's not working.